# Incorrect LastLogonTimeStamp Value of user in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I'm using LastLogonTimeStamp property of user in Active Directory to get the Last logon date time, Value isn't consistent,

Any one else faced same issue?

Can we trust the LastLogonTimeStamp?

Update:
It's just one Domain Controller

Comment: I found that, this is a known issue with LastLogonTimeStamp.

Comment: I have a work around. In my web app, I'm authenticating users using LogonUser api with LogonInteractive option. This in turn updates "lastLogon" property in specific Domain Controller. I query that in each DC, and I pick the latest one. Thats accurate.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/win2003/lastlogon.mspx

You would only use lastLogonTimeStamp if you have alot of domain controllers and don't need the most accurate results.  With a single domain controller use the lastLogon attribute.

Answer (score 2):

LastLogonTimeStamp by design only gets updated when the user logs in and the current value is between 9 and 14 days old. They did this to cut down on replication traffic in AD.

This [blog posting](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx) says it well:

> It is important to note that the
>   intended purpose of the
>   lastLogontimeStamp attribute to help
>   identify inactive computer and user
>   accounts. The lastLogon attribute is
>   not designed to provide real time
>   logon information. With default
>   settings in place the
>   lastLogontimeStamp will be 9-14 days
>   behind the current date.

If you want the real last logon information for a user, you have to pull the lastLogon attribute from each domain controller in the domain and use the most recent value.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a network with several DC (domain controllers)? They might be out of sync since the LastLogonTimeStamp will be updated on the DC that the user actually logs on, and synchronization might take some time.

Marc

Comment: Marc, It's just one Domain Controller. For some users it's showing a  days or two late.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever plan to have more than one DC, then LastLogonTimeStamp may not a reliable method for determining something like whether or not an account has grown "stale", since that attribute is not replicated to other DCs in many (most?) scenarios, depending on your domain functional level.

A better method for determining this is to look at "password age" (via the PasswordLastChanged attribute).  For example, if someone hasn't reset their password a week or two after it has expired (or some other time span depending on your particular environment), then there is a good chance that you have an orphaned account there.

Comment: It's going to be on one DC. 
I'm need the last login date, I dont think i can use the password age. I'm not sure how can i use that for last login datetime?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get an user's **True LastLogon** time neither by lastlogon or lastlogontimestamp in straight way..you need to do some custom work to get latest logon time.

By **LastLogon**

You need query lastlogon value from all the domain controllers and compare all values then get the highest logon time as True Last Logon

By **LastLogonTimeStamp**

Since it would be the replicable attribute you can query from only one DC but it will not give accurate result, it has precision around 14 days depends upon the attribute **msDS-LogonTimeSyncInterval**.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want the real last logon information for a user, you have to pull the lastLogon attribute from each domain controller in the domain and use the most recent value.

Unfortunately this isn't completely accurate.  I have used the lastlogon attribute and while it IS fairly close for most user accounts I've tested with this, I've come across many that return a date in 1600, and those that are close show at times that I know for certain the specified users weren't even able to login, for instance my own LastLogon showed at 7:50am when I know I signed in at 8:15am.

Many admins seem to sometimes desire to use this information to verify compliance with company policy.  Unfortunately Microsoft seems to have disregarded such intentions by design for system functionality purposes.

Comment: Dates in 1601 simply indicate it is "not set". In that instance, the lastLogon attribute on that DC for that account is "0" or null.